# PL/SQL: Loop through and alter REFCURSOR rows before returning to calling procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, ref-cursor

I have a refcursor in a function, declared like this:

```
my_cursor type_refcur_my
```

And populated as such:

```
        OPEN my_cursor FOR
        SELECT DISTINCT A.vegetable, A.animal, A.mineral, A.ID,                
           (SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(bcptr.bcptr_desc_l1,INSTR(bcptr.bcptr_desc_l1,')',-1)-3,3)
           FROM   doe D, ray R, me M
           WHERE ...) ID
           FROM artifacts A
           ORDER BY vegetable, mineral;

        RETURN my_cursor;
```

I need to perform an operation that involves another SELECT on all the rows in the recursor and use some logic to alter 2 of the column values before returning it. Something kind of like:

```
IF my_cursor.vegetable = (SELECT B.ID from vegetables B
WHERE my_cursor.vegetable = B.vegetable_description)
THEN
my_cursor.A.ID := B.ID
END IF;
```

My thought was to put this code after opening the cursor and before returning it. But this produces compile errors, and I cannot find an appropriate example online.I appreciate your help.

Comment: The best solution is to edit your original cursor statement and make the join to vegetables, but if you need to use the cursor as is, you could try wrapping my_cursor with a pipelined table function, http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_pipe_functions.html, and then create another cursor with the join of the table function and the vegetables table. Hope that makes sense...

Comment: I have decided to do this in the front-end Java application, but I am certain that your answer will be helpful in the future.